# remove strings from linq query

Tags: c#, regex, linq

I have a linq query that returns Names like:

```
Joe
Joe (1)
Joe Bloggs
Joe (2)
Joe Bloggs (1)
```

What is the best way to remove the Joe Bloggs entries from the list so my result set would be - the format for name been duplicates will always be (n) where n is the incremented number for that name:

```
Joe
Joe (1)
Joe (2)
```

I was using the below to attempt to remove the elements I needed

```
 newResults = results.Distinct().ToList();
```

However this it appears would only remove Duplicate entries.  I was hoping to use a regex expression in linq query to find any entries that are `Joe` and any entries that are `Joe (` but not sure if regex is the correct way to implement.

I have also plugged in a linq query as below:

```
var searchName = "Joe";
var results = names.Where(name => name.Equals(searchName)).ToList();
```

again this only returns 1 entry - can you include a regex in the .Equals to say find any names where the name equals the search name or equals the search name + space + (

Comment: [*What have you tried?*](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, stack traces, compiler errors - whatever is applicable). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive.

Comment: Updated with what I had tried - didnt think there was any reason to include this as it isnt working as I needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can you `Regex.IsMatch` method to get only these strings starting with `Joe`  followed by an optional `(1)`, `(2)`, etc. string:

```
 var pattern = @"Joe(?=(\W?\(\d+\))|$)";
 var results = names.Where(name => Regex.IsMatch(name, pattern)).ToList();
```

Based on the sample input you provided `results` will be `{"Joe", "Joe (1)", "Joe (2)"}`.

Comment: The value 'Joe' will be dynamic - could be Fred for example - I will have it in a variable called personName - can I add that varaible to your pattern in string.Format?

Comment: can you break down the pieces in the Regex to explain what each one is doing?  I have another requirement to find the complete word so if I have 'Name 1' and 'Test 1' and the '1' - the regex above will return 3 results if I pass in '1' but I would like it to just return one result - can I use the ^ in your regex to do this?

Comment: @Ctrl_Alt_Defeat `(?=` means followed by, `|` is "either, or", `$` means the string ends (i.e. it is only "Joe"), the rest simply matches "(1), (2), ...". If you have a different requirement you can always try posting a new question!

Answer (score 0):

You need to refine your query to return only the data that you want.  If this is not possible, then you must apply a further query to the collection once obtained.  Barring this, try using a loop structure to remove unwanted entries by comparing each item in the collection and then responding to the matches with desired code.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you correctly, you want to exclude records which contains "*Bloggs*" word, so...

```
List<string> joes = new List<string>{"Joe", "Joe (1)", "Joe Bloggs", "Joe (2)", "Joe Bloggs (1)"};

var qry = joes.Where(j=>!j.Contains("Bloggs"));
```

result:

```
Joe 
Joe (1) 
Joe (2)
```